# How can I get a list of tables ever used in a piece of code?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

Just want a list of all the tables ever created, manipulated, read-in or used in general (but not those that are in a defined library but aren't used). Should I use a log parser or is there a simpler way to do it? The code can change from time to time. Thanks.

Comment: Look at PROC SCAPROC but it requires you to run the process unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In general there is no easy way of doing this (in base SAS at least - I'm not sure about Enterprise Guide in particular). A log parser seems like the simplest way to go, assuming that all of your code writes sufficient information to the log to allow you to find what you want.